# Set Korean input type to default

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, language, accessibility

I often need to switch between French keyboard layout and Korean layout. However, by default, the input type of the Korean layout is set to English, so equivalent to a regular `QWERTY` keyboard. I may access the Korean typing mod by pressing the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key but for some reasons I cannot press this key (related to this topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055031/simulate-altgr-with-autoit).

So basically, how should I proceed for the Korean input type to be selected by default when I switch to the Korean layout ?

Comment: Which version of Windows? If Win8 can you post screenshots of the Language Control Panel applet?

Comment: I am using Windows 7